# not saving .txt file inside the folder using javafx

Tags: javafx, netbeans

I have created a small application but not `txt` file is not saving inside the folder .. it saving outside folder by the name of the folder... code is as follows.

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private Label label1;
    @FXML
    private Button button;
    @FXML
    private TextField txt;
    @FXML
    private Button save;

    Stage primaryStage;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        // System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        //label.setText("Hello World!");
        DirectoryChooser dc= new DirectoryChooser();
        File chosenDir = dc.showDialog(primaryStage);
        System.out.println(""+chosenDir);
    }

    @FXML
    private void save(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        DirectoryChooser dc= new DirectoryChooser(); 
        File chosenDir = dc.showDialog(primaryStage);
        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(txt.getText().toString());
        File f= new File(chosenDir+"user.txt");
        FileWriter f1=new FileWriter(f);
        f1.write(sb.toString());
        f1.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

Comment: Didn't you just mean to use [`File f = new File(chosenDir, "user.txt")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.io.File-java.lang.String-) (not `new File(chosenDir+"user.txt")`)?

Comment: I will try please wait..

Comment: @James_D it is working thank u verymuch ...